# How to increase the performance of a Spring Batch that read data from an Oracle AQ?

Tags: java, performance, spring-batch, oracle-aq

I have a Spring Batch code that read (dequeue) data from an Oracle AQ.

But to read only 100 rows, it takes 4 minutes!!

What it can be the problem with this reader? ¿How can i improve the performance?

This is the code from my custom reader that dequeue the data:

```
  final String queueOwner = "OWNER";
    final String queueName = "QUE_NAME";

    try (Connection aqconn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        aqconn.setAutoCommit(false);
        Class.forName("oracle.AQ.AQOracleDriver");

        AQSession aqSession = AQDriverManager.createAQSession(aqconn);

        AQQueue queue;
        AQMessage message = null;
        AQDequeueOption deqOption = new AQDequeueOption();
        AQObjectPayload payload;

        Data data= new Data();
        queue = aqSession.getQueue(queueOwner, queueName);

        message = ((AQOracleQueue) queue).dequeue(deqOption, DataAq.getORADataFactory());

        payload = message.getObjectPayload();
        DataAq dataAq= (DataAq) payload.getPayloadData();

        --Some validation

        aqconn.commit();

        aqSession.close();
        return saldo;
   }
```

I've try already using JmsItemReader, but it was always giving me this error "Payload factory must be specified for destinations with ADT payloads" even if i set a message listener, so i've give up with that configuration.

Comment: Why are you openning transaction/connection and close for every read?

Answer (score 0):

To read from Oracle AQ with SpringBtach I'm using JmsTemplate.

Here is a sample of the configuration i'm using :

```
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException, SQLException {
        return AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(dataSource());
    }


    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        SimpleMessageConverter converter = new SimpleMessageConverter();
        jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(converter);
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName("YOUR_QUEUE_NAME");
        return jmsTemplate;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        OracleConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:database");
        dataSource.setUser("usr");
        dataSource.setPassword("pwd");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

After you can use the JmsItemReader from SpringBatch